# Selenium Webdriver.get() throws a timeout error even though page has loaded

Tags: python, selenium

I am using selenium to automate some work that I do in Google Analytics. The program was working fine for months until a few days back.

It first logs into google and then opens the relevant analytics pages and gets the required information. 
The logging in process works fine and it opens the first analytics page and saves all the info.

Then when I make it move to another page by using the get function, the page loads in a few seconds but the program gets stuck and throws a timeout error after a few mins.
This is the part of the code that gets stuck:

```
## Getting GEOLOCATIONS
print("Getting GeoLocations")
driver.get("{}{}/{}".format(geourl, key[i], geo[i]))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((
        By.XPATH,"//*[@id=\"ID-reportHeader-reportToolbar"]/div[1]/div[2]/span[2]"
        )))
```

The code gets stuck in the get() function. This is the error after a few mins:

```
Getting GeoLocations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "seo.py", line 122, in <module>
    driver.get("{}{}/{}".format(geourl, key[i], geo[i]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 248, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout
  (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.140)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881),platform=Linux 4.4.0-112-generic x86_64)
```

I am using the latest chromedriver 2.35 and selenium version 3.90.

Comment: It's most likely because the page didn't reach a complete state within the allowed time. Check the console from the browser, you'll probably see that the browser failed to load a resource.

Comment: Yes, There are a few resources that failed to load. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Can you update the question with the full error stack trace?